# How to bind all ports in docker to their corresponding ports on host

Tags: docker

How to bind all ports in docker to their corresponding ports on host?

The `-p` option requires to manually specify each exposed port and its corresponding host port:

```
docker run -p 4568:4568
```

The `-P` option binds all ports, but to random ports on host.

Is there an option like `-P` that binds all ports to the same port on host?

Comment: No. Use docker-compose?

Comment: It looks contradictory as there are high chances that same services might be running on the host machine. and also from security point of view it is advised to open and map with expected ports only.

Comment: It is possible if you are using the host network:
`docker run --network host`  **BUT** it is not secure, would be better to bind ports explicitly and works only for Linux.

Comment: one option as mentioned by @RidgeA to use --network host and second option is to use that container IP instead of exposing port

Answer (score 1):

You can create **run_me.sh** script that will do "docker run" with all required parameters and port mappings.

```
  #!/bin/bash

  docker run --rm \
     --name container-name \
     -p 8080:80 \
     -p 8443:443 \
     -i image-name-here
```